# Iterate through txt files and find rows that are not in all files

Tags: shell, powershell

I have folder with 3 text files. 
File 1, call it test1.txt has values

```
11
22
22
```

test2.txt has values

```
11
22
22
33
```

test3.txt has values

```
11
22
22
33
44
44
```

How can I get my final result equal to (New.txt)
to be:

```
44
44
```

This values is not in the other 2 files so this is what I want.

So far code:

```
$result = "C:\NonDuplicate.txt"

$filesvalues=gci "C:\*.txt" | %{$filename=$_.Name; gc $_ | %{[pscustomobject]@{FileName= $filename; Row=$_ }}}

#list file where not exists others file with same value
$filesvalues | % {
                    $valtockeck=$_
                    [pscustomobject]@{
                                        Val=$valtockeck  
                                        Exist=$filesvalues.Where({ $_.FileName -ne $valtockeck.FileName -and $_.Row -eq $valtockeck.Row  }).Count -gt 0
                                     }  

                 } | 

                 where Exist -NE $true | 
                 % {$_.Val.Row | out-file $result -Append}
```

This is the error:

```
Where-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert the "Exist" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
At line:16 char:23
+                  where <<<<  Exist -NE $true | 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
#list files/values couple
$filesvalues=gci "C:\temp\test\test*.txt" -file | %{$filename=$_.Name; gc $_ | %{[pscustomobject]@{FileName= $filename; Row=$_ }}}

#list file where not exists others file with same value
$filesvalues | % {
                    $valtockeck=$_
                    [pscustomobject]@{
                                        Val=$valtockeck  
                                        Exist=$filesvalues.Where({ $_.FileName -ne $valtockeck.FileName -and $_.Row -eq $valtockeck.Row  }).Count -gt 0
                                     }  

                 } | 

                 where Exist -NE $true | 
                 % {$_.Val.Row | out-file "c:\temp\test\New.txt" -Append}
```

Comment: Hi this is great but when I Run the code it does not work. I had to delete the -file you have on your first line. And after, It stills gives me an error. Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert the "Exist" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock". where <<<<  Exist -NE $true. ....... Is it a powershell version error?? Thanks for the help again!! :D

Comment: or modify to:  where {$_.Exist -NE $true }

Comment: Yeah I have version 1.0 :(  It seems like the Exist = $filevalues.Where({....  has to be changed too. Because it gives me an error "Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'Where'."

Comment: Try Where-object instead where

Answer (score 1):

```
$file1 = ".\test1.txt"
$file2 = ".\test2.txt"
$file3 = ".\test3.txt"
$results = ".\New.txt"

$Content = Get-Content $File1
$Content +=  Get-Content $File2

Get-Content $file3 | Where {$Content -notcontains $_}| Set-Content $Results
```

Answer (score 1):

Other solution 1

```
#get couple files/values
$filesvalues=gci "C:\temp\test\test*.txt" -file | 
    %{$filename=$_.Name; gc $_ | 
        %{[pscustomobject]@{FileName= $filename; Row=$_ }}}

#group by value and filter by number of distinct filename, then extract data into file
($filesvalues | group -Property Row | where {($_.Group.FileName | Get-Unique).Count -eq 1 }).Group.Row | 
    out-file "C:\temp\test\New2.txt" -Append
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`Compare-Object` cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object)'s purpose is to compare *two* sets of inputs.
*Nesting* two `Compare-Object` calls yields the desired output:

```
$file1Lines = Get-Content .\test1.txt
$file2Lines = Get-Content .\test2.txt
$file3Lines = Get-Content .\test3.txt

(Compare-Object `
  (Compare-Object -IncludeEqual $file1Lines $file2Lines).InputObject `
  $file3Lines |
    Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '=>'
).InputObject
```

- `Compare-Object` outputs `[pscustomobject]` instances whose `.InputObject` property contains the input object and whose `.SideIndicator` property indicates which operand the value is unique to - `<=` (LHS) or `>=` (RHS) - and, with `-IncludeEqual`, if it is contained in *both* operands (`==`).
- `-IncludeEqual` in the *1st* `Compare-Object` call not only outputs the lines that *differ*, but also includes the ones that *are the same*, resulting in a *union* of the lines from file `test1.txt` and `test2.txt`.
- By *not* specifying switches for the *2nd* `Compare-Object` call, only [objects wrapping] the lines that *differ* are output (the default behavior).
- Filter `Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '=>'` then filters the differences down to those lines that are unique to the RHS.

---

To **generalize the command to N > 3 files** and output to a new file:

```
# Get all input files as file objects.
$files = Get-ChildItem .\test*.txt

# I'll asume that all files but the last are the *reference files* - the
# files for which the union of all their lines should be formed first...
$refFiles = $files[0..$($files.count-2)]

# ... and that the last file is the *difference file* - the file whose lines 
# to compare against the union of lines from the reference files.
$diffFile = $files[($files.count-1)]

# The output file path.
$results = ".\New.txt"

# Build the union of all lines from the reference files.
$unionOfLines = @()
$refFiles | ForEach-Object {
  $unionOfLines = (Compare-Object -IncludeEqual $unionOfLines (Get-Content $_)).InputObject
}

# Compare the union of lines to the difference file and
# output only the lines unique to the difference file to the output file.
(Compare-Object $unionOfLines (Get-Content $diffFile) | 
  Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '=>').InputObject |
    Set-Content $results
```

<sup>Note that `Set-Content` uses the Windows legacy single-byte encoding by default. Use the `-Encoding` parameter to change that.</sup>

Comment: Perfect! But lets say I have 10 text files following the same logic as my Example. How would I only get the lines that are not present in the first 9 txt files? Thanks for you help!! :)

Comment: @Cesar: My pleasure; please see my update for a generic N > 3 solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, instead of writing the result in the $results file, save it in a variable $tmpResult and then do the same check as above for $tmpResult and $file3 to gain a final result. And if you have more than 3 files, you can create a loop to repeat the check.

But something is missing in the code above  - you only get the unique lines in file2 and not those in file1.